# Git branching combines files with master?

Tags: git, github

I was just practicing branching and something unusual is happening when I create a branch and make a change within that branch is also making changes on the Master branch . Any idea ?

the commands I used were

```
mkdir stuff
cd stuff
git init . 
echo "#python" > test.py 
git add . 
git commit -m "add file"
git branch dev
git checkout dev 
echo "#python2" > test123.py
git checkout master
```

When i look at the content of master it includes test123.py which it should not ???

Comment: You're branching `dev` off of `master` after your `add file` commit. So yes, they will still be in the same state. All `git branch` does is create a new branch pointer at the current commit.

Comment: should not changes made in the dev branch after is created, be separate from the master ?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have not committed the file for the dev branch. Basically this will stay as a local modification, which are moving along your application even after changing branches.
If you don't want to commit the file you can type

`git stash`

and switch to any branch, after that you can always get back to your branch and type

`git stash pop`

OR 

`git stash apply`

Comment: That is right. Files that are not added to the repository will remain untouched by git. If you switch branches, git will warn you if that would conflict with an untracked local file. Otherwise, the file will just stay there.

Comment: You can do `git status` to verify that there are untracked files. There is also an option on checkout to "clean the working tree" (careful with that).

Comment: The next word after `git stash` is never the path to a file: it's one of the keywords `save`, `apply`, `pop`, `drop`, and so forth. The default is `save`. (Otherwise this answer is fine, just the one glitch.)

Comment: @BackSlash, If this answer suits to you, could you please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks